# Replacing a Firebase database with an MS Sql database in an Angular application

Tags: sql-server, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed an Angular app that can send http posts to a free Firebase database.

I went for Firebase initially, as it was easy to include its URL, etc... in my Angular post service, while following a tutorial.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsService {

  error = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createAndStorePost(title: string, content: string) {

    const postData: Post = { title: title, content: content };
    
    this.http
      .post<{ name: string }>(
        'https://angulartutorial-2169d-default-rtdb.europe-west4.firebasedatabase.app//posts.json',
        postData,
        {
          observe: 'response'
        }
      )
      .subscribe(
        responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        },
        error => {
          this.error.next(error.message);
        }
      );
  }
```

Now, I would like to be able to connect to my local SQL server database, located in:

```
C:\Users\Reem\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB
```

**How do I modify my post, fetch, delete, etc... to connect to a SQL database, instead of a Firebase database via a URL?**

This is the content of my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=My-Project-E14040DF-A185-44F2-BE25-B9C9D5E768B4;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I am looking around to find a recent and simple little app or example that shows how to connect an Angular 10 app to a MS SQL database, but I cannot seem to find one that would readily show what I am looking for.

I would appreciate any help.